# Delphi 10.2 - TImageControl livebinding

Tags: sqlite, delphi, save

I`m using Delphi 10.2 with LiveBindings. Everything works, except handler with images.  My database is MariaDB (tried with SQLite too). My problem is cant save image using livebinding. Load from database is very simple, but I cant understand why not save.

My Table contains 5 fields (int, varchar, blob). When Bind my grid with image Field and click inside Grid, error says: cannot find file (Object). I tried with TImageControl too, but when user select new Image (insert or update) and click save record, application simply clear image control.

Sorry, english is not my main.

Comment: I don't understand. You have the bidirectional binding of a dataset BLOB field to the `Bitmap` property of a `TImage`, or `TImageControl` control and then happens what? You call `Insert` method, load a different picture to the image control and `Post` the changes? Or what exactly do you do? Could you elaborate what exact actions do you do, please (ideally with some code as well)?

Comment: Yes, I`m using bidirectional binding of BLOB field to the BitMap. Load occurs normal and using navigator too. So, I dont use any methods only livebindings, and when change picture with navigator to save. TImageControl only refresh, maybe not applying post. For use livebindings with blob I`ll need change behavior?

Comment: This is not related to FireDAC (that you probably use as you mentioned MariaDB), nor `TBindNavigator`, nor used DBMS. You can reproduce the same if you simply `Insert` a tuple, select a picture, fill in the key and `Post` the tuple to DBMS. It simply doesn't save the image.

Comment: Hello Victoria. I`m continue trying. Inside installation some samples projects with LiveBindings and images. TBindLink FMX Example and BindGridLink Example not working too. Compile and execute with Administrator does not work. Click on Modify Record, after click Image Control, File Dialog appears, choose new Image. Image Control renders, but when click save (post). The control is repainted with old image and not save.

Comment: It's certainly a Delphi bug. I'll try to find out what is missing for the image transfer.

Comment: Thanks for your Help. This bug occurs with Memo too, with livebinding 2 fields with Memo and same behavior.